# help with probability theory question

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $v$ be a probability measure on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $v$ has no atom. Let $\left(x^{i, N}\right)_{1 \leq i \leq N}$ be the sequence of real numbers defined by:
$$
\begin{aligned}
x^{1, N} & \left.=\inf \{x \mid v((-\infty, x]) \geq \frac{1}{N+1}\right\} \\
x^{i+1, N} & =\inf \left\{x \geq x^{i, N} \mid v\left(\left(x^{i, N}, x\right]\right) \geq \frac{1}{N+1}\right\} \quad 1 \leq i \leq N-1 .
\end{aligned}
$$
Then
$$
-\infty<x^{1, N}<x^{2, N}<\cdots<x^{N, N}<+\infty
$$
and, for any real number $\eta$, there exists an integer number $N(\eta)$ such that, for any $N$ larger than $N(\eta)$,
$$
d\left(v, \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N \delta_{x^{i, N}}\right)<\eta
$$
where $d(\mu, \nu)= inf | \int f d \mu - \int f d\nu|$ where f is Lipchitz function bounded by 1.
I will post my attempt within some minute, the problem is the code from overleaf to here is posing problem and weird text is being shown, I am trying to figure out.
we call $L_{N}= \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N \delta_{x^{i, N}} $

$ | \int f dv- \int f dL_{N}|$\
\begin{align*}
    &= \left|\sum_{i=1}^{N}\frac{\int f dv - \int f(x^{i, N}) dv}{N}\right| \\
    &\leq \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{N}|\int f dv - \int f(x^{i, N}) dv |}{N} \\
    & \leq \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{N}\int |f dv - f(x^{i, N})| dv }{N}
    & \textrm{as f is lipchitz with constant bounded by }1 \\
    & \leq \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{N}\int |x - x^{i, N}| dv(x) }{N}
\end{align*}
I am not able to now use above properties, may be we need to break domain and do something else, but I couldn't realize. Can someone help regarding this. Thank you.